# Error converting bytecode to dex

Tags: java, android

I am pretty new to Android. When I build my current project I got this error:

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause:
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;

This is my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.+'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
compile 'com.kyleduo.switchbutton:library:1.4.0'
compile files('libs/JTransforms-3.1-with-dependencies.jar')
compile 'com.github.Semantive:waveform-android:v1.2'
compile files('libs/TarsosDSP-Android-latest.jar')
}
```

I'm using `gradle 2.13` and `gradle-build 2.1`.

There were someone tell me to clean the project but it didn't work. Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if i understand you question i hope this answer can help you.

You can increase the memory size that the dexer process is allowed to use.
Open the ini file that is located in:
C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Anywhere Software\Basic4android 
Change this line:.

MaxRamForDex=1024 To:.

MaxRamForDex=1536

Comment: sorry could you explain more detail? I'm using OSX and I couldn't find that file

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be a wrong package name in any of your Java class files,I had the same issue and this was because of this problem.Try to rebuild your project and check again.

Answer (score 1):

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
```

You have repeated a reference